# Border color of UITextField view in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to set the border color of UITextField inside dynamic cell of UITableView.
That's the code:

```
UIColor *searchBorderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:160.0/255.0
                            green: 160.0/255.0
                            blue:160.0/255.0
                            alpha: 1.0];
cell.searchField.layer.borderColor = [searchBorderColor CGColor];
```

I tried putting it in cellForRowAtIndexPath, willDisplayCell, didEndDisplayingCell - it doesn't work.
Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cell.searchField.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
```

or use any other width value. Also you can add rounded corder:

```
cell.searchField.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0f;
```